# Complex graphics in power point

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, vector-graphics

A friend of mine can create really stylish power point presentations. He uses for example cool graphics such as:

[image]

However, when looking at this graphic it seems to be really a power point graphic as it`s many shapes that are within the power point format?

[image]

I was guessing that he creates these in a graphic design tool as vector graphic  first and then somehow imports them into power point. Power Point then somehow recognizes this graphic.

Any suggestions how to do this in power point? Is there really such an importing function?

Comment: Why don't you ask your friend how he does it? Then you can share the answer with us ...

Comment: it's better to group them together so that you can do things on them at once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing Mysterious about it, except your friend who is gifted in using PowerPoint.

All he is doing is inserting objects, rectangles, trapezoids or parallelograms,
formats them via right-click and "Format Shape...", then changes their Fill and
Line colors (and other attributes).

For learning to do the same, you may start with the article
[Add sizzle to your PowerPoint presentation with shapes and special effects](https://www.pcworld.com/article/2456424/add-sizzle-to-your-powerpoint-presentation-with-shapes-and-special-effects.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are two options here:

1. Draw it directly in Microsoft PowerPoint (as mentioned)
2. Draw it in another tool (for example, Adobe Illustrator or CorelDraw) and then import it into Powerpoint. This approach, depending on the tool, can offer additional capabilities and control over PowerPoint. Typically you might export the drawing in the Windows metafile (WMF) or enhanced metafile (EMF) formats and then select "Insert->Picture" in PowerPoint.